# select() blocks when there are some data to read

Tags: c, serial-port

I am trying to implement a blocking read on a serial port. I have the following code

```
int blocking_read(int input_fd,int wait_time){
    if(wait_time <= 0) return 0;
    fd_set set;
    FD_ZERO(&set);
    FD_SET(input_fd,&set);
    struct timeval wait_time_struct;
    wait_time_struct.tv_sec = wait_time / 1000000;
    wait_time_struct.tv_usec = wait_time % 1000000;
    int ret = select(1,&set,NULL,NULL,&wait_time_struct); 
    char a;
    int check=read(input_fd,&a,1);
    printf ("ret %d, check %d %02x\n",ret,check,a&0xFF);
    return ret;
}
```

the last 4 lines are just for a debug...
When I run this when I expect a message on serial port in a loop, the output is:

```
ret 0, check 1 ff
ret 0, check 1 ff
ret 0, check 1 c4
ret 0, check 1 d7
ret 0, check 1 00
ret 0, check 1 01
...
```

and the message I expect is `FF FF C4 D7 00 01....` so obviously, the `select()` block even though there is something to read... Can you please help me?

Comment: You might want to read [the `select` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html), pay close attention to the first argument.

Comment: And what does a zero return from select() mean? And what does FD_ISSET() say?

Comment: And what would a 1 return from select() mean?

Comment: that there is one filedescryptor ready to read from

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should use the select like that:

```
int ret = select(input_fd +1,&set,NULL,NULL,&wait_time_struct);
```

The argument name nfds kind of confused me, it just looks like an amount of file descriptors in the set. From manual

`nfds is the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1.`

Comment: does this solve your problem ? If so accept your answer. If not edit your question and remove this answer

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that.